# As3 Flash Builder Starling project "Stopped Responding"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash

I am making an actionscript 3 mobile project in flash builder. Everything was working fine until yesterday when I was getting an error,

"initial content not found"

When I compiled this error would show up in a popup box in flash builder. I realized that the swf (mine is called Heads.swf) was missing from bin-debug.
So I took an older Heads.swf that I had from before and put it in bin-debug. Well, that prevented the error from popping up, but now the app that plays in the simulator is not updated to what is it in the code. I can add traces, delete lines, etc., but the simulator just plays the old swf.

Cleaning the project and even making a new project and copying the src path isn't helping either. :/

Does anyone know why / what is this that is happening, and how do I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in bin-debug delete the your-project.swf, then go to "project" and choose "build project", that should take care of it.

Comment: Hi this doesn't work because build is not building a swf!